# Floating point additions vs products

Tags: tex-core, floating-point

I'm writing a small macro to draw a curve given some parameters in Tikz:

```
\newcommand{\beznorm}[4]{%x, y, width, height
    \def\x{#1}%
    \def\y{#2}%
    \def\w{#3}%
    \def\h{#4}%
    \def\sw{1/8 * \w}
    \def\sh{1/4 * \h}

    \draw [cyan, shift={(\x, \y)}, xscale=\sw, yscale=\sh]
        (0,0)   .. controls (1,0) and (1.75,.5) .. (2.5, 2)
        (2.5,2) .. controls (3,3) and (3.5,4)   .. (4, 4)
        (5.5,2) .. controls (5,3) and (4.5,4)   .. (4,4)
        (8,0)   .. controls (7,0) and (6.25,.5) .. (5.5,2)
    ;
}
```

This works well, but I also wanted to have a way to specify the rightmost `x` and `y` coordinates rather than the width and height, so I wrote:

```
\newcommand{\beznorm}[4]{%lx, by, rx, ty
    \def\x{#1}%
    \def\y{#2}%
    \def\w{#3-\x}%
    \def\h{#4-\y}%
    \def\sw{1/8 * \w}
    \def\sh{1/4 * \h}

    \draw [cyan, shift={(\x, \y)}, xscale=\sw, yscale=\sh]
        (0,0)   .. controls (1,0) and (1.75,.5) .. (2.5, 2)
        (2.5,2) .. controls (3,3) and (3.5,4)   .. (4, 4)
        (5.5,2) .. controls (5,3) and (4.5,4)   .. (4,4)
        (8,0)   .. controls (7,0) and (6.25,.5) .. (5.5,2)
    ;
}
```

Suddenly, this does not work anymore. So I started looking into floating point operations in LaTeX, and I'm somewhat starting to realize that the first version maybe should have not worked either. So my questions are:

- Why my products and divisions in the first version seem to work fine?
- Why the subtraction in the second version does not work?

Comment: always show a small but complete document, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Missing brackets? `\sw` expands to `1/8 * \w` which in turn expands to `1/8 * #3-\x`, while I believe you want `1/8 *(#3-\x)`.

Comment: @campa Ah, it seems that was it, thanks! I keep forgetting to think in terms of expansions, I was just thinking that latex would resolve the math at each assignment..